# Modifying "upload image to firebase" code for a class component into a function component

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, hook

I'm trying to upload a user profile picture to Firebase Storage. This is in an expo managed RN project.

I've found this bit of code that is supposed to work, however it is meant for a class component and I'm using function components throughout my app for the sake of simplicity:

```
onChooseImagePress = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync();
    //let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync();

    if (!result.cancelled) {
      this.uploadImage(result.uri, "test-image")
        .then(() => {
          Alert.alert("Success");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          Alert.alert(error);
        });
    }
  }

  uploadImage = async (uri, imageName) => {
    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();

    var ref = firebase.storage().ref().child("images/" + imageName);
    return ref.put(blob);
  }
```

My code so far looks like this:

```
const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
    const pickImage = async () => {
          let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            quality: 1,
          });
      
          console.log(result);
      
          if (!result.cancelled) {
            setImage(result.uri);
          }
        };
```

This allows me to pick an image, but I've no idea how to upload it. I was wondering if someone could maybe guide me in the right direction to be able to modify the code I've found into working in a function component.

**Edit**

Doing this:

```
const pickImage = async () => {
      let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3],
        quality: 1,
      });
  
      console.log(result);
  
      if (!result.cancelled) {
        setImage(result.uri);
        this.uploadImage (result.uri, "test-image")
        .then(() => {
          Alert.alert("Success");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          Alert.alert(error);
        });
      }
    };

    const uploadImage = async (uri, imageName) => {
        const response = await fetch(uri);
        const blob = await response.blob();
    
        var ref = firebase.storage().ref().child("images/" + imageName);
        return ref.put(blob);
      }
```

Returns an error message.

Comment: If you have code that isn't working the way you expect, your question needs to explain what that code is supposed to do, and include the specific error.  Without that, we don't really know what's wrong.  I suggest reading about how to create a minimal complete example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ok, I get it, however I'm unsure as to what else I'd have to add. That is the only snippet of code I have that isn't working. I'd just need someone to point me in the right direction to upload images to firebase storage from the expo image picker. Thanks a lot for the guide to building a reprex.